spring boot tutorial example with annotation from Lombok causes compilation error
I have copied the following from a tutorial on Spring Boot.
package com.example.SpringStarter.models;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String  firstname;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account");
    private List<Post> posts;

}


The annotations after @Entity cannot be compiled:
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete ConstructorHeaderName
        Syntax error, insert ")" to complete ConstructorDeclaration
        Syntax error, insert ";" to complete ConstructorDeclaration
        Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
        Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration

        at com.example.SpringStarter.models.Account.<init>(Account.java:17) ~[classes/:na]

Why is it not working? All of the annotations are from the lombok import, and I'm running java version "1.8.0_411".


Check the line 17. There is a ; at the end.

@Mar-Z I don't see any stray punctuation, added screen shot of IDE

@Mar-Z There WAS a semicolon on line 30! That was it.
